# ListView's OnItemClick does not work

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I made a listview.
Using [this](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/) tutorial link 
It works fine.
But the problem is when i try to add onitemclick listener in its activity class the click action does not work.i just want to show a toast message.And here it the code for onItemClickListener

```
listViewCity.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 

                    String item = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }  
        });
```

Why it doesn't work anybody can tell me???

Comment: Do you have any buttons or other clickable views inside your 'Item'?

Comment: ya,the url link there..check the link i mention

Comment: Try TextView.setFocusable(false); in get view method

Answer (score 1):

***If you are getting an exception or a force close, you should have mentioned it.***

First of all, your OnItemClickListener is wrong, because the View that is passed to your OnClickListener is not a TextView so You can not just cast it to a TextView.

You can fix it using the following:

```
listViewCity.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
        String item = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cityName)).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }  
});
```

---

Try what I just did and it should work. If it doesn't work, you may need to remove the line `android:autoLink="web"` from your xml file.

---

The attribute `android:autoLink="web"` is making your View's TextView Clickable. As I mentioned in my comment, if any of your subviews is clickable, your OnItemClickListener will not receive events, because it will be consumed by the children.

Comment: it doesn't work when i use your code.but after removing the `android:autoLink="web"` it works.thanks.But the url does not work :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

Since you are using a customadapter you will have to do this in your customadapter class to handle onclicks of the listview...

```
convertView.setClickable(true);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View paramView)
                    {
                      //if you want you can use the "position" value to get the desired row items.
                    }
                    });
```

Comment: See you are using a custom adapter class which extends the Array Adapter, in such cases you cannot handle the onClicks of the listview the way you have written.. The code that i have posted will help you. Since you are loading the listview rows which are custom, handling onClicks in the adapter class does the work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
listViewCity.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                     String item = listViewCity.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }  
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting each view I needed to click to clickable and then added the listener. I put the following method inside the customized adapter (in getView method). Something like this:

```
public void setViewsClickable(int position) {
        myView.button.setClickable(true);
        myView.radioButton.setClickable(true);
        myView.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // what this button should do
            }
        });

        myView.radioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // what clicking this radio button should do
            }
        });

    }
```